# ¿Por qué solo me cambia los valores en la última iteración?

Tags: java, java-swing, hilos

Estoy tratando de entender un poco sobre los hilos, y estoy tratando de crear una pequeña implementación de uno de ellos, pero estoy teniendo un problema. El objetivo es que, conforme cada iteración, cambie los valores de unas etiquetas que tengo en el swing. El detalle es que solo me cambia los valores en la ultima iteración, siendo que debería cambiarla cada 4 segundos. Realicé una prueba imprimiendo los valores de cada iteración y eso si lo hace bien, pero en el swing, solo lo cambia la última iteración.

```
public void practicaNumeros(JLabel etiquetaA, JLabel etiquetaB) {
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {

                //Se crea un número aleatorio
                int numero = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, 1 + 1);

                //Se crea una letra aleatoriamente
                String letraAleatoria = this.letraAleatorias();

                //Se crea un número aleatorio
                int numeroAleatorio = this.numeroAleatorios();

                /*
                System.out.println("Número aleatorio: " + numero);
                System.out.println("Contador del for: " + i);
                System.out.println("Letra: " + letraAleatoria);
                System.out.println("Número: " + numeroAleatorio)
                */

                if (numero == 0) {
                    etiquetaA.setText(String.valueOf(numeroAleatorio));
                    etiquetaB.setText(letraAleatoria);
                } else {
                    etiquetaA.setText(letraAleatoria);
                    etiquetaB.setText(String.valueOf(numeroAleatorio));
                }

                Thread.sleep(4000);
            }

        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        }
    }
```

Comment: Dices que estás haciendo pruebas con hilos.... ¿Dónde está ese código? ¿Dentro de un hilo? ¿Cómo lo lanzas? Muéstranos el código relevante.

Comment: En estos casos lo mejor es debuggar tu aplicacion para encontrar el fallo. Veo dos posibles escenarios. 1) Tu hilo acaba antes de que se vea la aplicacion por lo que toma el ultimo valor. 2) No se esta refrescando el componente correctamente mostrando los cambios. Como han dicho antes comparte el hilo al que llamas

Comment: Como te dice Victor Manuel el problema es que tus componentes visuales no se refrescan. Debes llama algo como *repaint* después de cambiar el texto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los componentes swing deben actualizarse en el hilo de eventos, de lo contrario los resultados no van a tener sentido, como te está pasando.

Puedes usar una javax.swing.Timer, que es una clase para generar eventos cada determinado tiempo; y "durante esos eventos" actualizar componentes swing.

Pero si quieres probar varios hilos a la vez y actualizar componentes swing quizás te funcione mejor con un javax.swing.SwingWorker. Esta clase sirve para poder correr un hilo o varios y coordinar publicaciones para poder actualizar los componentes swing en el hilo de eventos.

Ahora que si lo que quieres es aprender de hilos en particular, te recomendaría que no lo hicieras con componentes swing, sino con el System.out u otro medio que no te vaya a revolver.

Comment: Muchas gracias, seguí tu consejo y pude solucionarlo.